# Making a longer and slightly more diagonal slash in css

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Currently I have a setup like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="bp-rating">
  <sup class="small-num">8.5</sup>
  <span class="slash">/</span>
  <sub class="total-num">10</sub>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bp-rating{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding:10px 5px;
  border:1px solid #222;
  display:inline;
}
sup{
  color:green;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/pEzKko)

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image: Slash]

I'm wondering if there is anyway to make a slash slightly more diagonal and slightly longer.

Is it possible to stretch the line while also keeping a thin line and would it be better to just remove the slash character completely and just do it another way like with `background`?

Comment: This is scss not css. Some may be confused about it. By the way, you can use pseudo element(:before, :after) to create a line for you and just rotate it using transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer, you can increase height or width if you want, or change background color:

HTML

```
<div class="bp-rating">
  <sup class="small-num">8.5</sup>
  <span class="slash"></span>
  <sub class="total-num">10</sub>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.bp-rating{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding:10px 5px;
  border:1px solid #222;
  display:inline;
  sup{
    color:green;
  }
  .slash {
    height:1px;
    width: 40px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
  }
}
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzk7a6ky/)

Comment: Worked like a charm I was thinking this was the best route to take just want to make sure:)

Comment: Awesome! @NooBskie

Answer (score 2):

Check this out!

Achieved by `transform`ing a `div` (line) -45degrees. 
(change color using `background` of the `slash` class.

Guess you can start on this to get what you desire.

```css
.bp-rating {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  display: inline;
}
.bp-rating > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.bp-rating .small-num {
  color: green;
}
.slash {
  width: 35px;
  height: 1px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: inline-block;
  background: #111;
}
```

```html
<div class="bp-rating">
  <sup class="small-num">8.5</sup>
  <span class="slash"></span>
  <sub class="total-num">10</sub>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform to create a slash instead of using the text.

```css
.bp-rating{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding:10px 5px;
  border:1px solid #222;
  display:inline;
  sup{
    color:green;
  }
}
.slash{
  height: 25px;
  width: 0px;
  transform: skew(-45deg) translate(5px, 8px);
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bp-rating">
  <sup class="small-num">8.5</sup>
  <span class="slash"></span>
  <sub class="total-num">10</sub>
</div>
```